# Android (Emulator) permission denied error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to create a folder using following command in terminal of Android emulator running on Windows 7 environment.

```
$ cd sdcard
$ mkdir pictures
```

But this gives  "mkdir fail for pictures, permission denied"  error. How can I correct this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean from adb shell? What directory are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I tried to create new directory in sdcard and used terminal emulator.

Comment: By "terminal emulator" do you mean [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)?

Comment: No......you can find it under Dev tools of Emulator.

Comment: This should do trick for such kinds of error 

mount -o remount, rw /mnt/sdcard

Answer (score 2):

Try

> $ adb shell "mkdir /sdcard/pictures"

More available at [How to create sub-folder in SD Card of Android Emulator, using adb](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card-of.html)

Comment: Then it gives "adb: permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you created an SD Card for your AVD.

In "Android Virtual Device Manager" -> Choose your AVD -> Click "Edit..." -> Specify Size for your SD Card and click OK.

Next time you'll launch your AVD you could use:

```
$ adb shell
# mkdir /mnt/sdcard/your_folder
```

to create your folder.

Good luck.

Answer (score -6):

Add this on the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What is the purpose of using internet permission for this problem ? I'm talking about emulator not about special application. I confused.